# Using Servicestacks c# redis client how do I set the URN?

Tags: c#, servicestack, servicestack.redis

I have code like:

```
public Vehicle NewOrUpdate(Vehicle vehicle)
{
        try
        {
            RedisManager.ExecAs<Vehicle>(r =>
            {
                r.Store(vehicle); //save new or update
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorMessage = ex.ToString();
            HasError = true;
            throw;
        }
        return vehicle;
}
```

How can I set the URN for the item being added? I see the CreateUrn extension on the object but I don't see a way to set it explicitly. By default it creates a URN of "urn:vehicle:Id". Id like to have a URN like "urn:vehicles-{MySpecialId}:Id" is it possible to control this?

Or another way to ask this...
Can I make up my own URN for the objects I store?

```
Vehicle v = new Vehicle();
v.CreateUrn = "urn:mine";

RedisManager.ExecAs<Vehicle>(r =>
{
   r.Store(v); 
});
```

Comment: Looks like part of the answer might be: client.SetEntry("urn:vehicle-727", vehicle.CreateUrn<Vehicle>());

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's actually not to hard, if you know where to look.
I just create a list with any urn I want:

```
 string urn = String.Format("urn:dealer:{0}:vehicles", dealer.DealerId);
 var vehicleclient = client.As<Vehicle>();
 var vehicleList = vehicleclient.Lists[urn];
 foreach (var vehicle in dealer.Vehicles)
 {
    vehicleList.Add(vehicle);
 }
```

add the items to the custom list, and then the items can be recalled by using:

```
List<Vehicle> returnValue = new List<Vehicle>();
string urn = String.Format("urn:dealer:{0}:vehicles",DealerId);
using (var client = new RedisClient("192.168.42.128", 6379))
{
    returnValue = client.As<Vehicle>().Lists[urn].ToList();
}
```